# Masking Zip Codes with a For Loop Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I am trying to write a for loop that loops through a data frame and assigns either 0 or the first three digits of the given zip code depending on the population. My TA says I need to fix the second line to loop through the index rather than the length of the data frame but I am unsure how to move forward. Here's the question and my code.

"In this part, you should write a for loop, updating the df_users dataframe. Go through each user, and update their zip code, to Safe Harbor specifications: If the user is from a zip code for the which the "Geographic Subdivision" is less than equal to 20,000, change the zip code in df_users to '0' (as a string). Otherwise, zip should be only the first 3 numbers of the full zip code. Do all this by directly updating the zip column of the df_users DataFrame."

```py
for item in range(0, len(df_users)):

    population = zip_dict[df_zip.loc[item, 'population']]
    if population <= 20000:
        df_users.loc[item, 'zip'] = '0'
    else: 
        new_zip = (df_users.loc[item, 'zip'])[:3]
        df_users.loc[item, 'zip'] = new_zip
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of your input? What df_users and df_zip looks like.

Comment: Please [provide a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `df.to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard)

Answer (score 0):

### Use [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

- Using a `for-loop` with a pandas dataframe is not advised and leads to poor performance.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# dataframe example
df = pd.DataFrame({'pop': [10000, 20000, 30000], 'zip': [12345, 97000, 87390]})

   pop    zip
 10000  12345
 20000  97000
 30000  87390

# update zip based on pop
df['zip'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.where(x['pop'] < 20000, '0', str(x['zip'])[:3]), axis=1)

   pop  zip
 10000    0
 20000  970
 30000  873
```

### If you have to use a `for-loop`

- **You Shouldn't**, this is a `pandas` [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern)
- `range(0, len(df_users))` produces a list from `0, 1, ..., len(df)-1`, however, the index may not be ordered numerically from `0, 1, ...`.  This is probably why you were instructed to change to `df.index`
- Presumably, the zip codes are numeric.  `(df_users.loc[item, 'zip'])[:3]` can't be used with an `int`, which is why `str(df.loc[i, 'zip'])[:3]` is used.  If the `zip` column is `object` or `str` type, then you can use `df.loc[i, 'zip'][:3]`

```py
for i in df.index:
    pop = df.loc[i, 'pop']
    if pop < 20000:
        df.loc[i, 'zip'] = '0'
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'zip'] = str(df.loc[i, 'zip'])[:3]
```